# Dedicating a server for latency test

Tags: linux, bandwidth, ping, latency

I've created a server to test bandwidth from employees working remote (using speedtest.net mini), but was wondering if anyone knew of a way to setup some software in linux to test latency and possibly keep track of the results.

I essentially want to test the latency between a client at their house and a server in a dmz.
I am currently running RHEL5

Comment: Yes, plenty of already made software does latency collecting.  Google, ping monitoring.

Comment: Check out smokeping.

Comment: i think it is useless, every client latency will be different, what will it prove?

Comment: As it stands, it's difficult to determine what your actual problem is.  If it is simply "Whats a good way to test latency for remote connections?" then you're off topic here.  However, I think there's more to it, and this has some potential to become a useful question.  If you can provide some details, such as your proposed solution along with a specific question about some aspect of it's implementation, i'm sure you would get more useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out smokeping and that didn't do what I wanted. I searched for a couple of days before posting this question. I put an inquiry in with Ookla and they pointed me to NetGuage, will does exactly what I need.  http://www.ookla.com/netgauge

I run Netguage on a server in our DMZ, and people that are having any kind of connectivity issues, we can point them to the server, and get a baseline of their latency, packet loss, upload/download speeds, which is a great first step in troubleshooting.